# Unable to apt-get update on IPv6-only ubuntu server

Tags: apt, server, amazon-ec2, aws

Whenever I try to `apt-get update` on my IPv6-only ubuntu server, the command fails with `connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.102.108). - connect (101: Network is unreachable`. Is there a way to update and install packages on IPv6-only instances? I need packages like build essentials, etc.

Comment: Can you ping that URL? Are you using sudo apt-get or just apt-get? Knowing the version of Ubuntu may help to assist you.

Comment: You try to connect to an IPv4 only ubuntu mirror from an IPv6 only server. this does not work. Use a IPv6 mirror e.g. `us.archive.ubuntu.com` -> `kazooie.canonical.com`. change the hostnames in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. IPv6 support can be tested with `ping -6 <HOSTNAME>`